# Store sensitive files in a secure store

Tags: files

In a project that I'm working on we are required to temporarily store sensitive files (pdf, images, ...). These files are uploaded by a user over the internet and we would like to make sure that only the application (in the context of a user) can access these files.

How is this requirement achieved today in 2020? Are there some products that cover these requirements? Do you know the general term for what I am looking for? Is this a file vault?

I'm not sure if I am completely off topic with this question at serverfault. But I would be happy if someone could point me directions since I'm pretty new to such a topic. Thank you.

**Update**

The protection should be applied on the disc where we temporarily store the files. Nobody should who has access to the filesystem should be able to access/copy the files and be able to read/view it. So I guess the answer is, as you already mentioned, encryption right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General guidelines require encryption in transit, encryption on disk.

You can use basic PGP to encrypt the files before they are submitted with only the public key of users that are permitted to access the files, but without more information the answer is going to be vague.

**Update**
Sounds like this could be a website? if so HTTPS for transit, FDE (full disk encryption) for encryption on disk would be sufficient.

If your are programming this application you could implement something like a PGP library so only the application can decrypt the files or even many S3 implementations (tons of documentation online)

Comment: I have update my question. Hope its not that vague anymore

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt the files with the public key of a certificate that only your application has access to.